# Cant write on DynamoDB from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

So, I was trying to write to a DynamoDB from lambda following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ut5CkSz6NR0) but only works once, and never again, I dont know why happen.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//AWS.config.update(region: 'us-east-2'});
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-2'});

async function createRequest(UUID, coin, hour){
    const params = {
        TableName: '<Table_Name>',
        Item: {
            'UUID': UUID,
            "Moneda": coin,
            "Hora": hour
        }
    };
    try{
        ddb.put(params); //This should be await, but I need to write on console only if was ok
        console.log("Inserted:",params); //This do the log, thats make me think it working
    }catch(err){
        console.error("Oh no!",err); //Never print this error
    }
}
```

"<Table_Name>" is, eventually, the name of my table on DynamoDB. If you are wondering why I write from lambda? Is becouse I do some process before calling this method. I have all [Execution role permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) that AWS required, but never works again.

I have this output

```
Response
null
```

If I change the line to await...
`await ddb.put(params);`
In the log right above, I have the *I delete the json response for private reasons, have nothing to do on this context*
[Await for DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DW14.jpg)

Comment: Are you saying that your Lambda function runs only 1 time and then fails all times after?

Comment: You should await your ddb.put, otherwise console.log display even if it's failing

Comment: @AntoninRiche Didnt work anyway

Comment: @smac2020 yep... Works once, and when I try again, never works, even I re do another lambda, and it doesn't work either

Comment: This works only once because `put()` does overwrite your first entry and does not create a new one, if the hash key/sort key are the same.

Comment: @Jens But ```put()``` is the insert on DynamoDB doesn't?

Comment: @AlfaRojo It is literally the first two sentence of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html): `Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item. If an item that has the same primary key as the new item already exists in the specified table, the new item completely replaces the existing item.`

Comment: @Jens But I already delete the table and create new ones, and still doesn't working

Comment: @AlfaRojo Please define what "does not work" means. Do you get an error? What are the exact steps that are you doing. What is the exact input data you are using. What is what you expect to happen. What is the rest of your code. It is at the point not really possible to have any idea what you are doing and what is happening.

Comment: @Jens I mean that the lambda dont send the data, or dynamo dont save the data... I update the post with the output null... The first log print

Comment: Can you await, print the result and show us?

Comment: @AntoninRiche I add the screanshot at the end, on *await for db*

Comment: try this ddb.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});

Comment: @Nonik same null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't `await`ing the response from the `put`. You have an `async` function but the Lambda is exiting as soon as it gets done sending the request. That means it doesn't have a response to give you. The current SDK for JavaScript requires that you add `.promise()` to the call too. So the code would look like this:

```
await ddb.put(params).promise();
```

I think the rest of your logic is fine. It will only hit the `console.log` right after that line if the `put` doesn't throw. If it does you will end up in the `catch` block.